# how to run php script in phpeclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I was downloaded the phpeclipse from the eclipse downloads.

i have wamp in my machine(c:/wamp/).

i set path like c:/wamp/php/php.exe in system environmental varariables path.

now i want to run php script from phpeclipse.

what i have to do to run php script.

is there any runconfigurations in the phpeclipse.

if exists...how can i configure those things?

is there any documents exists related to that?

is anybody explain me in detail?

thanks in advance.

regards
kk

Answer (score 1):

In order to run your php project in Eclipse you need to edit the server configuration in the Eclipse . do the following .

- In Eclipse Go to  `Window->preferences`
- On the left panel you see `PHP` expand the tab click on `PHP Servers`
  [image]
- On the right side you will see  Name as `Default local host with url` click on it and `edit` it
  [image]
- A pop up will appear you will see two menus `Server` and `Path Mapping` click on Path Mapping
  [image]
- Enter the Path of the virtual directory ie path of wamp www directory , if you are on linux just enter `/var/www`.
- Finally run the project

Hope it helps !